# How to understand .netcore add scoped

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to understand the implementation or logic on how it works based on documentation. I am creating a .NET Core API

services.AddScoped<ICommanderRepo, SqlCommanderRepo>();
Documentation states that:

> Adds a scoped service of the type specified in TService with an
> implementation type specified in TImplementation to the specified
> IServiceCollection.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddScoped<TService, TImplementation>(this IServiceCollection services)
    where TService : class
    where TImplementation : class, TService;
```

I want to know what is TService. And what is TImplementation. Because if i see it first time i dont know what it simply means.

SqlCommanderRepo implements ICommanderRepo interface.

```
public class SqlCommanderRepo : ICommanderRepo
{
    private readonly CommanderContext _context;

    public SqlCommanderRepo(CommanderContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

}
```

And CommanderContext extends DbContext

```
public class CommanderContext : DbContext
{
    public CommanderContext(DbContextOptions<CommanderContext> opt) : base(opt)
    {

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is TService. And what is TImplementation?

`TService`: The type of the service to add.

The contract for the service in your case  is `ICommanderRepo`.

`TImplementation` : The type of the implementation to use.

The concrete type that implements the service in your case is `SqlCommanderRepo`.

From the source codes of [ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), `AddScoped<TService, TImplementation>`  adds a scoped service of the type specified in TService with an implementation type specified in TImplementation to the specified IServiceCollection.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a scoped service of the type specified in <typeparamref name="TService"/> with an
        /// implementation type specified in <typeparamref name="TImplementation"/> to the
        /// specified <see cref="IServiceCollection"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TService">The type of the service to add.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TImplementation">The type of the implementation to use.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> to add the service to.</param>
        /// <returns>A reference to this instance after the operation has completed.</returns>
        /// <seealso cref="ServiceLifetime.Scoped"/>
        public static IServiceCollection AddScoped<TService, TImplementation>(this IServiceCollection services)
            where TService : class
            where TImplementation : class, TService
        {
            if (services == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
            }

            return services.AddScoped(typeof(TService), typeof(TImplementation));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a scoped service of the type specified in <paramref name="serviceType"/> to the
        /// specified <see cref="IServiceCollection"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> to add the service to.</param>
        /// <param name="serviceType">The type of the service to register and the implementation to use.</param>
        /// <returns>A reference to this instance after the operation has completed.</returns>
        /// <seealso cref="ServiceLifetime.Scoped"/>
        public static IServiceCollection AddScoped(
            this IServiceCollection services,
            Type serviceType)
        {
            if (services == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
            }

            if (serviceType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceType));
            }

            return services.AddScoped(serviceType, serviceType);
        }
```

Note:

[Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options)

- Transient objects are always different; a new instance is provided to
  every controller and every service.
- Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across
  different requests.
- Singleton objects are the same for every object and every request.

Comment: Hi, @Kirpal Singh, please let us know if you have updated information on this issue.